# Add a checkbox as Woocommerce admin product option that hides related products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

To make this as simple and as easy as possible, I'm trying to add this checkbox on the top row next to the product type selector where you would normally find `Virtual` and `Download`.

The idea is to have the checkbox there so that no matter the product type, it is always available.

This is what I've tried:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_type_options', 'remove_related_products_checkbox' );        
function remove_related_products_checkbox() {           
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( 
        'id' => '_remove_related_products', 
        'class' => '', 
        'label' => 'Remove Related Products?'
    ) );      
}

add_action( 'save_post_product', 'related_products_checkbox_save' );
function remove_related_products_checkbox_save( $product_id ) {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    if ( 'post.php' !== $pagenow || 'product' !== $typenow ) return;

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    if ( isset( $_POST['_remove_related_products'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_remove_related_products', $_POST['_remove_related_products'] );
    } else 
        delete_post_meta( $product_id, '_remove_related_products' );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'remove_related_products_checkbox_display', 1 );
function remove_related_products_checkbox_display() {
    global $product;

    if ( ! empty ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_remove_related_products', true ) ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work… Any advice please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a bit outdated since WooCommerce 3 and there are some mistakes.

Try the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'product_type_options', 'hide_related_products_option' );
function hide_related_products_option( $fields ) {
    $fields['hide_related'] = array(
        'id'                => '_hide_related',
        'wrapper_class'     => '',
        'label'             => __('Remove Related Products'),
        'description'   => __( 'Remove/Hide related products.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'default'           => 'no'
    );
    return $fields;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'hide_related_products_option_save' );
function hide_related_products_option_save( $product ) {
    $product->update_meta_data( '_hide_related', isset( $_POST['_hide_related'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no' );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'remove_related_products_checkbox_display', 1 );
function remove_related_products_checkbox_display() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->get_meta('_hide_related') === 'yes' ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Add checkbox to product type option in Woocommerce backend product edit pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043644/add-checkbox-to-product-type-option-in-woocommerce-backend-product-edit-pages/50043717#50043717)

Comment: Thanks, very kind of you. I understand that this might be a new question, but I just now realized that there's a comma after the text, how do I remove that? Right now it is Remove Related Products?: and I would like it to be Remove Related Products

Comment: @KevinAronsson Updated, removed "?"…

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide the Related Products section you can display a checkbox to disable related products. You just need to add the following snippet to your functions.php.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'codeithub_add_related_checkbox_products' );        
  
function codeithub_add_related_checkbox_products() {           
woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( 
   'id' => 'hide_related', 
   'class' => '', 
   'label' => 'Hide Related Products'
   ) 
);      
}
  
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'codeithub_save_related_checkbox_products' );
  
function codeithub_save_related_checkbox_products( $product_id ) {
   global $pagenow, $typenow;
   if ( 'post.php' !== $pagenow || 'product' !== $typenow ) return;
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if ( isset( $_POST['hide_related'] ) ) {
      update_post_meta( $product_id, 'hide_related', $_POST['hide_related'] );
    } else delete_post_meta( $product_id, 'hide_related' );
}
  

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'codeithub_hide_related_checkbox_products', 1 );
  
function codeithub_hide_related_checkbox_products() {
    global $product;
    if ( ! empty ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'hide_related', true ) ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
    }
}
```